# Do we call it "a lounge" in a cinema?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We have a waiting area in a cinema.

[image]

As showed in the picture, when you go into a cinema, you see a waiting area facing the counter where people buy movie tickets, or popcorn and drinks.

You can sit in the waiting area waiting to go into the cinema room.

A lounge often refers to a room. I am not sure if we can say it if it is not a room but just an area.

Do we call this area "**a lounge**"?

Comment: If it has comfortable seats, it can be a 'waiting lounge'.

Comment: The area where people assemble before going in to see a theatre or cinema show is often called a [foyer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/foyer) .

Answer (score 1):

In British English, this part of a cinema is called **the foyer**.

In American English, it is called **the lobby** (they also call cinemas 'movie theatres').

Not all cinemas have seating like you have highlighted. A room that is mainly comprised of comfy seating like this is usually called *a lounge*, but if it is part of something larger then the seating may be called *a lounge area*. So, if you wanted to specifically highlight that area specifically, you could refer to it as *the lounge area of the foyer/lobby*.